# Is the Kawthoung/Ranong pass passable in August?

Tags: thailand, borders, myanmar

According to wikivoyage, there are [4 open border crossing points](http://wikitravel.org/en/Myanmar#By_land) between Myanmar and Thailand. Our first idea was to cross the "Three Pagoda Pass" near Kanchanabury but it say that it's not open for foreigners now. So, as we wanted to visit Mergi islands, the closest pass is Kawthoung/Ranong but seems that the road between Myeik and Kawthoung is a bit difficult.

Our trip is in August.

So the question is: it's better to go back to Mae Sot pass or do we have any chances to get to Kawthoung and cross?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was in Myanmar in March 2016.

First of all, there is no pass at Kawthoung/Ranong, you take a small boat to cross the Kra Buri inlet/river, it takes 30min or so.

I travelled from Hpa-An, north of Mawlamyine all the way down to Kawthoung, the road is actually pretty good because it was rebuild recently. There were two small constructions sites on the way, but we just had a wait a few minutes. The information about the bad road is outdated, don't believe people who try to sell you tickets for a boats or planes in Kawthoung.

There are buses from Kawthoung up north, but I didn't use any public transport this time, but I've heard it is improving. It still takes some time.